# JPQL Custom Query to Retrieving data with ExampleMatcher & Pageable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

How to using JPQL Custom query using ExampleMatcher?

I'm trying to retrieve the child from parent size. 
Since I'm not allowed to add another method on the child side.

I need to filter and paging for showing the child because the child contains so-many row data.

This is my repository.

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, String> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Child c where c.parent.id =:id")  
    public List<Child> findChildById(String id, Example example, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Note: This query is working fine, if without example and pageable as parameters.

That method give me the an error :

```
    Error creating bean with name 'parentRepository': 
        Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
        Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.test.ParentRepository
.findChildById(java.lang.String,org.hibernate.criterion.Example,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable) 
        but parameter 'Optional[example]' not found in annotated query 
        'SELECT c FROM Child c where c.parent.id =:id'!
```

Comment: You have an extra parameter in method signature. Delete example variable from method signature.

Comment: What's your plan with the Example? Do you want to find parents by example? or do you want to find children with example with a given parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters you pass to method annotated with `@Query` should be used in query, in your example this should be something like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Child c where c.parent.id =:id")  
public List<Child> findChildById(@Param("id") String id);
```

Comment: Yes. I know about that., but i don't know how to add or create query when using ExampleMatcher.